# Need to merge 2 folders that have hundreds of thousands of files in each. VB.net

Tags: vb.net, file, merge, copy, xcopy

I need to merge these folders that have a TON of files in each directory. I would use folder.copy but that takes forever.

I have been using xcopy process to handle this for the most part but I have been getting errors from xcopy saying that there are duplicates when there are none. So I am trying to find a solid work around that is as fast or even faster then xcopy.

What I have tried before is:

```
Private Sub MergeF(ByVal TargetFolder As String, ByVal MergeeFolder As String)
    For Each F As String In IO.Directory.GetFiles(MergeeFolder)
        If IO.File.Exists(IO.Path.Combine(TargetFolder, IO.Path.GetFileName(F))) Then
            Dim FileA As New IO.FileInfo(IO.Path.Combine(
                MergeeFolder, IO.Path.GetFileName(F)))
            Dim FileB As New IO.FileInfo(IO.Path.Combine(
                TargetFolder, IO.Path.GetFileName(F)))
            If FileA.Length <> FileB.Length Then
                Dim index As Integer = 1
                Do
                    Dim NewFileName = IO.Path.Combine(TargetFolder,
                        IO.Path.GetFileName(F.Insert(F.Length - 4, CStr(index))))
                    If IO.File.Exists(NewFileName) Then
                        index += 1
                    Else
                        IO.File.Copy(F, NewFileName)
                        IO.File.Delete(F)
                        Exit Do
                    End If
                Loop
            End If
        Else
            IO.File.Move(IO.Path.Combine(MergeeFolder, IO.Path.GetFileName(F)),
                IO.Path.Combine(TargetFolder, IO.Path.GetFileName(F)))
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: XCopy determines duplicates by name, not by content or file date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-copy-directories

async should speed things up also;

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/asynchronous-file-i-o

if that is not fast enough, then I would think your next option would be trying with straight win32api

to convert code to vb you can use;

https://codeconverter.icsharpcode.net/
or
https://converter.telerik.com/

- Goodluck!

Comment: This morning I seen this again and the hundred thousands registered this time, I would recommend an index of some sort as Oliver said below!

Answer (score 2):

The problem of your implementation is that you are calling `File.Exists` inside of the loop. This scans the files in the target directory again and again and makes it slow. A better approach is to load the file names of the files in the target directory into a [HashSet(Of T)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-5.0). Lookups in this collection are very fast - much faster than `File.Exists`.

```vb
Private Sub MergeF(ByVal TargetFolder As String, ByVal MergeeFolder As String)
    Dim targetFiles = New HashSet(Of String)(
        IO.Directory.GetFiles(TargetFolder) _
            .Select(Function(f) IO.Path.GetFileName(f)),
        StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)

    For Each sourcePath As String In IO.Directory.GetFiles(MergeeFolder)
        Dim file As String = IO.Path.GetFileName(sourcePath)
        Dim targetPath As String = IO.Path.Combine(TargetFolder, file)

        If targetFiles.Contains(file) Then
            Dim sourceInfo As New IO.FileInfo(sourcePath)
            Dim targetInfo As New IO.FileInfo(targetPath)
            If sourceInfo.Length <> targetInfo.Length Then
                Dim index As Integer = 1
                Do
                    Dim fileWithoutExt =
                    Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)
                    Dim extension = Path.GetExtension(file)
                    file = fileWithoutExt & index & extension
                    If targetFiles.Contains(file) Then
                        index += 1
                    Else
                        targetPath = IO.Path.Combine(TargetFolder, file)
                        targetFiles.Add(file) 'Upate the HashSet
                        IO.File.Move(sourcePath, targetPath)
                        Exit Do
                    End If
                Loop
            End If
        Else
            targetFiles.Add(file) 'Upate the HashSet
            IO.File.Move(sourcePath, targetPath)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Note that I also diminished the number of `Path.Combine` and `Path.GetFileName` by using appropriate variables. I called the file names without directory `...File` and the full path `...Path`.

I initialized the `HashSet` with `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase`, to make it ignore the character case of filenames, as the Windows file system ignores the case as well.